# Symfony: secure delete link with CSRFProtection

Tags: php, symfony1, csrf

I have a delete link to delete a Comment object by ID `/comment/:id/delete`

In order to secure this link I add a csrf token to the link

```
$CSRFTokenForm = new BaseForm();
$link = url_for(..., array('_csrf_token' => $CSRFTokenForm->getCSRFToken()));
```

and in the executeDelete i use the `checkCSRFProtection()` method, and it all works fine.

The only thing is that each comment is displayed by a partial, and each partial creates it's own `BaseForm()` in order to create the token, which is waste of time since they're all the same..

Do you have a better idea on how to make it more efficient, like maybe a static `getCSRFToken()` method or creating a global `BaseForm()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use SF's method => delete. It creates the CSRF token for you:

```
<?php 
    echo link_to('comment/' . $comment->getId() . '/delete', 
             array(
                 'method'  => 'delete', 
                 'confirm' => 'Do you really want to delete the comment??', 
                 'title'   => 'Delete'
             )
         ); 
?>
```

Comment: and if i use `jq_link_to_remote()`?

Comment: I don't know the jQuery Plugin for Symfony. But you can try the same: `jq_link_to_remote($name, array('method' => 'delete', ...) , $html_options = array())`

Comment: It doesn't work.. anyway, I don't really like the way symfony outputs the delete link.. is there anyway to get the csrf without creating a new `BaseForm()` every time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's a  jQuery Plugin error. If you are using sfJqueryReloadedPlugin - 1.4.3 you need to change the source code of the file jQueryHelper in the plugin's directory and put "BaseForm" instead of "sfForm" in the "csrf => 1" sectuo

Answer (score 0):

With the jQuery Plugin try:

`jq_link_to_remote('comment/' . $comment->getId() . '/delete', array('csrf' => 1))`

Found it in the [sourcecode](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfJqueryReloadedPlugin/1.2/trunk/lib/helper/jQueryHelper.php#L340) and they do it with a BaseForm instance, too.